# Facebook oauth flow advantage over direct access token

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

Fb auth process seems to be:

- a pop up open on a fb auth page, and if permissions are granted, it pings my server with a code
- I'm then able to trade that code for an access token using my app secret (from my server)

This obtained access token will eventually expire, and then I'd just need the user to login again to provide a fresher access token.

But then on iOS with the FBSDKLoginKit, I can get an access token directly with no server involved. So what's the point of the first more complex flow? Why is fb not issuing an access token directly to the web client (that can relay it to my server) ? And why things looks different between a web client and a mobile client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressed in the OAuth 2.0 standard in its [breakdown of client types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1):

> **user-agent-based application**
>
> A user-agent-based application is a public client in which the client code is downloaded from a web server and executes within a user-agent (e.g., web browser) on the device used by the resource owner. Protocol data and credentials are easily accessible (and often visible) to the resource owner. Since such applications reside within the user-agent, they can make seamless use of the user-agent capabilities when requesting authorization.
>
> **native application**
>
> A native application is a public client installed and executed on the device used by the resource owner. Protocol data and credentials are accessible to the resource owner. It is assumed that any client authentication credentials included in the application can be extracted. **On the other hand, dynamically issued credentials such as access tokens or refresh tokens can receive an acceptable level of protection. At a minimum, these credentials are protected from hostile servers with which the application may interact. On some platforms, these credentials might be protected from other applications residing on the same device.** [emphasis mine]

So apparently Facebook is following this advice and assuming that native applications - but not web applications - can protect the access token.